# How can i dynamically fill drop down menu depending on some other drop down menu?

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have two drop down menus. In first, you select country, and in second, you should be able to select city. Cities should be different depending on selected country. Both countries and cities are loaded from database.

There are two tabels in database, with following rows:

- countries

  - countryId
  - name
- cities

  - cityId
  - name
  - countryId

This is index:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <select>
        <?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM countries");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value="' .$row['countryId'] .'">' .$row['name'] .'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select>
        <!-- Here goes select from countries -->
    </select>
</body>
```

How to fill second select?

Comment: You can do it with ajax.

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (html, dynamic, dropdown) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

Put some name to your first select,lets call it here as first_select and call the second select box as second_select

Hope this helps you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#first_select").change(function() {
        $.get('getcities.php?first_select=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#second_select").html(data);
        }); 
    });

});
</script>

<form  method="get">
<select name="first_select" id="first_select">
       <?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database") or die(mysqli_error());
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM countries") or die(mysqli_error());
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value="' .$row['countryId'] .'">' .$row['name'] .'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>

    <select name="second_select" id="second_select"></select>
</form>
```

Create a file called getcities.php and

in **getcities.php**

```
$first_select= $_GET['first_select'];

$query = mysql_query("select * from cities where countryid = {$first_select}");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<option value='$row[cityid]'>$row[name]</option>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use some conditional logic, assign a variable to the selection they make for their country, ie, "countryChoice" then for your second dropdown, have another while statement that lists all cities with the countryChoice.

A little something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/*YOUR ACTION */">
    <select name='countryChoice' id='countryChoice'>
        <?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM countries");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value="' .$row['countryId'] .'">' .$row['name'] .'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select name='cityChoice' id='cityChoice'>
        <?php
            $countryChoice = $_POST['countryChoice'];
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cities WHERE countryId='$countryChoice'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value="' .$row['countryId'] .'">' .$row['name'] .'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    </form>
```

You may need to change it a little bit, I haven't worked with this in a while. But, I hope this gives you the right idea.

Or, as mentioned above, you can use Ajax.

Comment: Because the second dropdown is filled with a WHERE query, it only fills itself with what the first dropdown selection is.

Comment: php will not execute for second time except in ajax

Comment: Works on my test website.

Comment: without ajax no one can execute the php code secondtime.the second drop down will have to change on selection of the first select box value. without ajax we cant do that